# Error on cfscript version of cflogin

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016

I am trying to cflogin inside of a cfscript.

```
    cflogin() { 
        cfloginuser(
            name    = "Bob", 
            password    = "123", 
            roles   = "Account");
        };
```

When I run it I get an error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with cflogin or even cfscript. `application.cfc` has a line that looks like

```
<cfscript>
   component extends="framework.one" output="false" {


   this.name="pca-cf-355";
```

This is not a valid application name when using cflogin. The application name needs to be changed

```
<cfscript>
   component extends="framework.one" output="false" {


   this.name="pca_cf_355";
```

Note the use of underscores instead of dashes